# Call AJAX function in the beginning not just after change

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I've built a form that uses ajax to determine the number of text fields there should be based on a select field. It successfully adds the text fields based off the select field when it is changed, but it does not add the fields in the beginning before there is a change.

```
    $this->configuration['test'] = '3';
    $form['columnNum'] = [
        '#title'   => t('Number of Columns'),
        '#type'    => 'select',
        '#options' => [
            1         => '1',
            2         => '2',
            3         => '3',
            4         => '4',
        ],
        '#default_value' => $this->configuration['test'],
        '#empty_option'  => t('-select-'),
        '#ajax'          => [
            'callback'      => [$this, 'columnCallback'],
        ],
    ];

public function columnCallback(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $number   = $form_state->getValue(['settings', 'columnNum']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i += 1) {
        $columns[$i] = [
            '#type'  => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Column Title'),
            '#value' => $this->configuration['test'],
        ];
    }
    $content[] = [
        '#type'        => 'container',
        '#attributes'  => ['id'  => 'column_wrapper'],
        'columnTitles' => $columns,
    ];

    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#column_wrapper', $content));
    return $response;
}
```

I've attempted lines this

```
$this->columnCallback();
```

But that failed.
Is there a way to get an ajax callback in the beginning before the field as well? Or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the AJAX function at the beginning I simply built the form as it should be in buildForm. Like so

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->configuration['test']; $i += 1) {
        $columns[$i] = [
            '#type'  => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Column Title'),
            '#value' => $this->configuration['test'],
        ];
    }
    $form['column_wrapper'] = [
        '#type'        => 'container',
        '#attributes'  => ['id'  => 'column_wrapper'],
        'columnTitles' => $columns,

    ];
```